# Computationally Efficient SVG character paths that scale well

Tags: svg

I have just spent most of the last two days drawing computationally efficient svg paths for each of the A-Z characters of the Arial Rounded MT Bold font family. I needed these paths to cut out character shapes from other svg shapes and as my program does this very very frequently I want the paths to be as light as possible. I also wanted them to scale well up to 512px.

Whilst I know that I could have done this automatically in Inkscape by drawing text objects and converting the text objects to paths, the Inkscape generated paths are at least twice and sometimes over three times the size of the paths I include below.

My question is how could I have saved the last two days of my life which I will never get back. I could not find any online resource or tool to generate efficient svg paths for text characters of a chosen font family. Neither could I find any definitions anywhere of the cubic bezier curves used by each of the font characters. If I could have found the latter I would have written a program to do it as it is I had to use trial and error.

[image: Characters]

My SVG paths are listed below each positioned centrally on a 32x32 grid with a 28pt font size and they will all scale up to 512 pt with very close match to the original font.

```css
svg { width: 28pt; }
```

```html
<!-- A  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 13.6 7 C 15 5 17.3 5 18.6 7 L 25.4 24 A 2 2 180 0 1 22.1 25.8 L 20 21.2 L 12 21.2 L 10.2 25.8 A 2 2 180 0 1 6.9 24 Z M 13.5 17 L 18.5 17 L 16 10 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- B  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 19 6 C 26 7 24.5 14.6 21 15.4 C 26.2 16.4 27 25.2 19 26 L 10.3 26 A 2 2 90 0 1 8.3 24 L 8.3 8 A 2 2 90 0 1 10.3 6 Z M 12.3 9 L 12.3 14.2 L 17 14.2 C 21.1 14.2 21.1 9 17 9 Z M 12.3 17.4 L 12.3 23 L 17.5 23 C 22 23 22 17.4 17.5 17.4 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- C  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 24.3 19.5 C 24.3 22.5 21.8 26.3 17 26.3 C 2.9 27.3 2.9 4.7 17 5.7 C 20.8 5.7 24.1 7.9 24.3 12 A 1.8 1.8 180 0 1 21.3 13 C 20.9 12 19.5 9.2 17 8.8 C 8.4 7.7 8.4 24.3 17 23 C 19.2 23 20.7 20.5 21.3 18.5 A 1.7 1.7 180 0 1 24.3 19.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- D  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 16 6 C 22.5 6 25.2 10 25.2 16 C 25.2 22 22.5 26 16 26 L 10 26 A 2 2 90 0 1 8 24 L 8 8 A 2 2 90 0 1 10 6 Z M 12.1 9.1 L 12.1 22.8 L 15 22.8 C 20 22.8 21 20 21 16 C 21 12 20 9.1 15 9.1 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- E  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 8.5 7.5 A 1.5 1.5 90 0 1 10 6 L 22.1 6 A 1.5 1.5 180 0 1 22.1 9 L 12.5 9 L 12.5 14 L 21.3 14 A 1.5 1.5 180 0 1 21.3 17 L 12.5 17 L 12.5 22.8 L 22.3 22.8 A 1.6 1.6 180 0 1 22.3 26 L 10.2 26 A 1.6 1.6 90 0 1 8.5 24.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- F  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 9 8 A 2 2 90 0 1 11 6 L 21.5 6 A 1.5 1.5 180 0 1 21.5 9 L 13.1 9 L 13.1 14.3 L 20.2 14.3 A 1.5 1.5 180 0 1 20.2 17.3 L 13.1 17.3 L 13.1 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 9 24.3 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- G  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 21.8 21.5 L 21.8 18.5 L 17.9 18.5 A 1.5 1.5 180 0 1 17.9 15.5 L 23.9 15.5 A 1.5 1.5 90 0 1 25.4 17 L 25.4 22.5 C 25.4 23.7 21.8 26.3 17 26.3 C 2.9 27.3 2.9 4.7 17 5.7 C 20.8 5.6 24.9 7.9 24.9 11 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 21.5 12 C 21 11 19.5 8.7 17 8.7 C 8.1 7.7 8.1 24.3 17 23.3 C 19 23.3 21.8 22.2 21.8 21.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- H  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 7.5 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 11.5 7.6 L 11.5 13.8 L 20.4 13.8 L 20.4 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 24.4 7.6 L 24.4 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 20.4 24.3 L 20.4 17.1 L 11.5 17.1 L 11.5 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 7.5 24.3 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- I  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 14 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 18 7.6 L 18 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 14 24.3 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- J  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 18 8 C 17.8 4.8 22.2 4.8 22 8 L 22 20 C 22.2 28.4 8.5 28.4 8.7 20 C 8.7 17.3 12.4 17.3 12.5 20 C 12.5 24.2 18 24.2 18 20 L 18 24 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- K  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 8.5 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 12.5 7.6 L 12.5 15.2 L 21.3 6 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 24.1 8.6 L 18.6 13.8 L 25 23 C 27 25.9 23.7 27.3 21.8 25.6 L 15.9 16.5 L 12.5 19.8 L 12.5 24.5 A 2 2 180 0 1 8.5 24.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- L  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 9 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 13 7.6 L 13 22.7 L 21.7 22.7 A 1.6 1.6 180 0 1 21.7 26 L 11 26 A 2 2 90 0 1 9 24 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- M  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 6.3 7.9 A 1.9 1.9 90 0 1 8.2 6 L 10.5 6 C 12.5 6 12.3 6.5 12.6 7 L 16 19.6 L 19.4 7 C 19.8 6.3 20 6 21 6 L 23.7 6 A 1.9 1.9 90 0 1 25.6 7.9 L 25.6 24.5 A 1.8 1.8 180 0 1 22 24.5 L 22 10 L 18.1 25 C 17.1 26.8 14.9 26.8 13.9 25 L 10 10 L 10 24.5 A 1.8 1.8 180 0 1 6.3 24.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- N  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 7.6 8 C 7.6 5.9 10.4 4.4 12.1 6.9 L 20.7 20 L 20.6 8 C 20.6 4.8 24.4 4.8 24.4 8 L 24.4 24 C 24.2 27 21 27 19.4 24.5 L 11.4 12.2 L 11.4 24.4 C 11.4 27 7.6 27 7.6 24.4 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- O  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 16 5.6 C 29.1 4.9 29.1 27.1 16 26.3 C 2.9 27.1 2.9 4.9 16 5.6 Z M 16 8.8 C 8.3 8.5 8.3 23.4 16 23.1 C 23.7 23.4 23.7 8.5 16 8.8 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- P  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 17 6 C 26 5.5 26 18.7 16.5 18.2 L 12.4 18.2 L 12.4 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 8.4 24.3 L 8.4 8 A 2 2 90 0 1 10.4 6 Z M 12.4 9 L 12.4 15.1 L 16 15.1 C 20.8 15.1 20.8 9 16 9 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- Q  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 16 5.6 C 29.1 4.9 29.1 27.1 16 26.3 C 2.9 27.1 2.9 4.9 16 5.6 Z M 16 8.8 C 8.3 8.5 8.3 23.4 16 23.1 C 23.7 23.4 23.7 8.5 16 8.8 Z M 16.4 19.3 C 17.2 19.3 21.4 22.2 21.5 22.5 C 21.4 22.6 26.8 25.5 26.5 25.5 A 1.4 1.4 180 0 1 25 27.8 C 24.3 27.8 20 25 20 24 C 19 23 15 21 15 21 C 14.2 19.8 15.7 18.9 16.4 19.3 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- R  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 18 6 C 27 5.5 26.6 16.5 19.3 16.9 C 20.9 17.1 25.1 23 25 24.5 C 25 26.9 22.3 26.7 21.4 25.5 L 18 20 C 17 18.5 16.5 17.2 12.4 17.4 L 12.4 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 8.4 24.3 L 8.4 8 A 2 2 90 0 1 10.4 6 Z M 12.4 9 L 12.4 14.5 L 17 14.5 C 21.8 14.5 21.8 9 17 9 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- S  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 8.5 12.5 C 6.9 3.3 23 3.9 23 10.5 C 23 12.5 20.5 12.9 19.8 11.5 C 17.9 6.4 11.7 8.6 12.1 11 C 12.1 11.5 12 13 18 14.1 C 21 15.1 23.9 16 23.9 20 C 24 28.4 8 28.5 8 20 C 8.7 18 10.8 18.5 11.3 19.5 L 11.8 20.6 C 13.2 25 20.4 23.8 19.9 20 C 19.9 17.3 14 17.3 11.6 16 C 9.6 15 9 14 8.5 12.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- T  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 22.9 6 A 1.6 1.6 180 0 1 22.9 9.2 L 18 9.2 L 18 24.3 A 2 2 180 0 1 14 24.3 L 14 9.2 L 9.1 9.2 A 1.6 1.6 180 0 1 9.1 6 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- U  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 7.6 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 11.6 7.6 L 11.6 18 C 11.6 20.3 12 23.2 16 23.1 C 20 23.1 20.4 20.3 20.4 18 L 20.4 7.6 A 2 2 180 0 1 24.4 7.6 L 24.4 18 C 24.4 23.7 22 26.3 16 26.3 C 10 26.3 7.6 23.7 7.6 18 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- V  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 7.25 8.3 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 11 7 L 16 21.8 L 20.9 7 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 24.6 8.3 L 18.75 24 C 18.75 24 18.2 26.3 16 26.3 C 13.7 26.3 13 24 13 24 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- W  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 3.4 8 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 7.1 7 L 10.1 20.1 L 13.5 7.5 C 13.5 7.5 14 5.6 16 5.6 C 18 5.6 18.5 7.5 18.5 7.5 L 22 20.1 L 24.9 7 A 1.9 1.9 180 0 1 28.6 8 L 24.55 24.5 C 24.55 24.5 24.1 26.3 22.1 26.3 C 20.1 26.3 19.65 24 19.65 24 L 16 10.6 L 12.4 24 C 12.4 24 11.9 26.3 9.9 26.3 C 7.9 26.3 7.45 24.5 7.45 24.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- X  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 8.9 8.1 A 1.75 1.75 180 0 1 11.9 6.3 L 16 12.8 L 20.45 6.3 A 1.75 1.75 180 0 1 23.4 8.1 L 18.55 15.5 L 23.65 23.5 A 1.75 1.75 180 0 1 20.44 25.5 L 16 18.6 L 11.45 25.5 A 1.75 1.75 180 0 1 8.3 23.5 L 13.6 15.5 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- Y  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 8.1 8.15 A 1.8 1.8 180 0 1 11.15 6.25 L 16 14.1 L 20.95 6.25 A 1.8 1.8 180 0 1 24 8.15 L 18 17.45 L 18 24.4 A 2 2 180 0 1 14 24.4 L 14 17.45 Z
" /></svg>
<!-- Z  --><svg viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="
M 10 9 C 7.7 9 7.7 6 10 6 L 21.5 6 C 23.9 6 24.1 8.2 23.4 9.5 L 12.15 23 L 23 23 C 25.3 23 25.3 26 23 26 L 9.5 26 C 7.5 26 6.5 24 7.7 22.5 L 19 9 Z
" /></svg>
```

Comment: Masking/clipping the SVG shapes with `<text>` elements that use the actual font itself wasn't a viable solution?

Comment: _»my program does this very very frequently (so) I want the paths to be as light as possible«_ Have you measured how much actual size or complexity of vector outlines in input data affects your program's performance? (Honest question. I understand the urge for clean code, but I feel this question should be asked.)

Comment: @Sean I am not sure exactly what you meant by masking/clipping but an example of what I am doing with the paths is to cut out a letter sized hole in another shape, e.g. <svg width="32" height="32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d = 'M 8 1 A 6 6 320 0 0 3 3 L 0 29 A 2 2 230 0 0 2 31 L 30 31 A 2 2 130 0 0 32 29 L 29 3 A 6 6 40 0 0 24 1 Z M 13.6 7 C 15 5 17.3 5 18.6 7 L 25.4 24 A 2 2 180 0 1 22.1 25.8 L 20 21.2 L 12 21.2 L 10.2 25.8 A 2 2 180 0 1 6.9 24 Z M 13.5 17 L 18.5 17 L 16 10 Z' fill='#f90000' fill-opacity='1'/>
</svg>. Could I do this with your approach?

Comment: @myf. An important comment. To give you a flavour for the reason behind my question, my application is a full screen map based tool with hundreds (sometimes thousands) of icons superimposed over map tiles. The shape of each icon is defined by svg which is then translated into html canvas drawing commands. I start with svg input as I also need to display the icons in the html menus as well. As the map is panned and zoomed by the user the number of canvas redraws is astronomical so my mission is to make it as efficient as I possibly can. But I have not made any explicit measurements yet. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveBrooker Here's an example of where an SVG `<mask>` element is used to punch a hole in another shape. In this case, the mask contains a heart shape, but it could also just consist of styled text too, allowing you to punch a hole with any available font. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask

Comment: @Sean. Thank you. Learn something new every day! However parsing the svg mask into canvas commands might be tricky! See comment above for my dual use of my svg inputs.

Comment: @SteveBrooker does the hole-punching happen after it's drawn to the canvas? If it's done beforehand, you could just compose a new SVG that includes the mask and then draw that to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not find any online resource or tool to generate efficient svg
> paths for text characters of a chosen font family.

Try an online resource [Google font to SVG path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/)

This resource contains a large set of fonts and with a high degree of probability you will find the one you need
To optimize the SVG path, I used another online resource [SVG-Editor](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

Below are code examples for letters A and D:

### A

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56.2" height="67.5" viewBox="0 0 56.2 67.5">
  <g stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="28pt" fill="red" stroke-width="1" >
    <path d="M30.4 0L31.5 0A5 5 0 0 1 34.7 1.2Q37 3 39 7.6A115.5 115.5 0 0 1 41.8 14.9Q46.3 27.4 51.6 48.7A34.7 34.7 0 0 0 53.7 54.6 39.6 39.6 0 0 0 54.4 56 59 59 0 0 1 55 57.2Q55.9 59.1 56.1 60A2.3 2.3 0 0 1 56.2 60.5 7.1 7.1 0 0 1 54.3 65.4 6.7 6.7 0 0 1 52.8 66.8 5.4 5.4 0 0 1 50 67.5L48.9 67.5A10.3 10.3 0 0 1 47.1 67.4Q46.1 67.2 45.4 66.8A3.8 3.8 0 0 1 43.6 64.8 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 43.5 64.6Q43.3 64 43.1 62.3 42.9 60.3 42.5 58.4A45.4 45.4 0 0 0 41.8 55.5Q41 52.7 40 50.9A8.3 8.3 0 0 0 39.1 49.7Q37.3 47.6 29.8 47.4A64.5 64.5 0 0 0 27.7 47.4 63.6 63.6 0 0 0 24.1 47.5Q17.9 47.8 16.1 49.5 14.5 51.1 12.7 55.4A58.2 58.2 0 0 0 11.5 58.3 24.2 24.2 0 0 0 10.7 61 30.3 30.3 0 0 0 10.4 62.8 32.2 32.2 0 0 1 10.2 63.8Q9.9 65.5 9.5 66.1A2.6 2.6 0 0 1 8.3 67.1Q7.4 67.5 6 67.5A10.2 10.2 0 0 1 5.9 67.5 6.4 6.4 0 0 1 3.9 67.2 5.2 5.2 0 0 1 1.6 65.6 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 0 61.3 6.4 6.4 0 0 1 0.3 59.4Q0.9 57.5 2.5 55.2 5 51.7 11.8 33.9A661.1 661.1 0 0 0 11.9 33.7 642.7 642.7 0 0 1 15.6 24Q22.8 5.9 25.9 2.3A5.4 5.4 0 0 1 26.3 1.9 9 9 0 0 1 27.6 0.9Q28.5 0.4 29.3 0.1A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 30.4 0ZM25 40.5L31.5 40.5Q37.6 40.5 37.6 39L37.6 38.6Q37.6 37.9 35.1 27.9A1479.3 1479.3 0 0 0 34.3 24.8Q31.1 12.1 30 11.8A0.2 0.2 0 0 0 29.9 11.8L29.7 11.8A0.1 0.1 0 0 0 29.7 11.8Q29.4 12.2 27.9 15.6A404.3 404.3 0 0 0 24.8 22.3Q19.1 35.2 18.8 38.9A4.9 4.9 0 0 0 18.8 39.3L18.8 39.6Q18.8 40.3 20.5 40.3A8.6 8.6 0 0 0 20.7 40.3L21.4 40.4 25 40.5Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### D

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.1" height="73.4" viewBox="0 0 60.1 73.4">
  <g stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="28pt" fill="red">
    <path d="M23.4 0L25.9 0A48.6 48.6 0 0 1 37.6 1.3Q45.8 3.3 51 8.5A28.5 28.5 0 0 1 57.6 18.6Q60.1 25.1 60.1 33.2L60.1 33.5 60.1 34.8Q60.1 43.2 57.2 51.4A34.7 34.7 0 0 1 53.5 58.7 27.7 27.7 0 0 1 48.5 64.5 35.5 35.5 0 0 1 40.2 69.8 31.8 31.8 0 0 1 36.1 71.4 40 40 0 0 1 30.8 72.6Q28 73 24.7 73.2A95.4 95.4 0 0 1 18.8 73.4L17.6 73.4 16.4 73.4A194.1 194.1 0 0 1 11.8 73.3Q5.5 73.2 2.7 72.6A9.9 9.9 0 0 1 1.7 72.3 2.7 2.7 0 0 1 0.8 71.8Q0.2 71.3 0.1 70.5A3.6 3.6 0 0 1 0 69.8 1.3 1.3 0 0 1 0 69.5Q0.3 68.7 1.4 66.3A18.3 18.3 0 0 0 2.4 63Q3.8 57.6 3.8 47.8A154.8 154.8 0 0 0 3.8 46.9L4.4 31 4.5 28.6 4.7 20.3A419.5 419.5 0 0 0 4.7 17.7Q4.7 12.6 4.5 11.2 4.3 10 3.8 8.4A30.6 30.6 0 0 0 3.5 7.3 39.1 39.1 0 0 1 3.2 6.3Q2.8 5.1 2.7 4.5A2 2 0 0 1 2.7 4.2Q2.7 1.7 6.1 1.1A50.8 50.8 0 0 1 10.1 0.5Q15.4 0 23.4 0ZM15.3 27.1L15.2 28.7 15 33.7 14.9 35.4 14.7 41.2A88.5 88.5 0 0 0 14.7 42Q14.6 43.1 14.6 43.7L14.5 45.4Q14.4 47 14.4 47.8L14.3 49.4A26.8 26.8 0 0 0 14.3 51.1L14.2 52.7 14 58.4 14 61.5A5.1 5.1 0 0 0 14.1 62.8 3 3 0 0 0 15.9 64.9Q17.6 65.7 20.7 65.8A28.2 28.2 0 0 0 21.4 65.8L23.7 65.8A24.2 24.2 0 0 0 32 64.4 20.7 20.7 0 0 0 41.4 57.5Q44.2 53.9 46 48 47.8 42.1 47.8 34.7L47.8 33.8A45.1 45.1 0 0 0 47 25Q44.6 13.1 35.1 8.8 31.3 7.2 26.6 7.2L24.2 7.2Q18.8 7.2 17.2 8.8A2.4 2.4 0 0 0 17 9 4.2 4.2 0 0 0 16.5 10.2Q15.7 12.7 15.7 18.9A278.9 278.9 0 0 0 15.5 21.5Q15.3 25 15.3 27A39.3 39.3 0 0 0 15.3 27.1Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The path for that "optimized" D is at least 6 times larger than the D in the question.

Comment: @Sean The optimization was swinging the number of digits after the decimal point and was reduced from 4 to one. Any font size can be selected on `Google font to SVG path` online resource.

Comment: I misunderstood and thought you had run the custom paths from the question through the optimizer.

Comment: My chosen font (used in the question) is not available in the online resource you mention.

Comment: @Steve Brooker There are a lot of fonts on the specified resource, you can choose a font similar to your font The main thing in the future is that you can get the necessary patches in a few clicks for any complex font